# AttributeError: 'Customer' object has no attribute 'json' fastapi

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, model, fastapi

i have model called customer has following fields

```
class Customer(Base):
    __tablename__ = "customer"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True,index=True)
    name = Column(String(256))
    mobile = Column(String(256))
```

this is my query

```
def get_referal_details_lms(db1: Session, mobile:str):
    data= db1.query(models.Customer).filter(models.Customer.mobile == mobile).first()
    print (data)     ## <db.models.Customer object at 0x7f6902d8e340>
    print (data.json())    ##AttributeError: 'Customer' object has no attribute 'json'
    return data
```

What is issue here and to convert json in same model i have **User model** and for that it is working fine the on;y difference is User from one table and Customer from other table.i have two databases sessions and its not problem with db's.

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    email = Column(String(256))
    mobile = Column(String(256))
```

query for this model

```
def get_user(db: Session, id: int):
    data=db.query(models.User).filter(models.User.id == id).first()
    print(data)    ## <db.models.User object at 0x7f6902d8e340>
    print(data.json())  ##{'mobile': '11111111', 'id': 1, 'email': None}
```

Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 1):

SQLAlchemy models in general have no `json` method. That must be something defined in your code somewhere, that's not defined for the `Customer` class.

Comment: def json(self):
 yes under customer class i defined json method and it worked thanks